# Product data is not getting inserted in phpmySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add products through PHP inside PHP MySQL but somehow the code is not inserting the data inside the database while running without any errors. I am not sure if there's any mistake in the PHP or in the PHP MySQL. I hope I'll get some answers here. Here's my code:
HTML

```
<div id="content">
        <form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="productName" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
            <input type="text" name="regularPrice" placeholder="Regular Price">
            <input type="text" name="discountedPrice" placeholder="discountedPrice">
            <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="productImage">Add Product</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
<?php
  $msg = "";
  
    // If upload button is clicked ...
    if (isset($_GET['productImage'])) 
    {
    
        $productName = $_GET['productName'];
        $quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
        $regPrice = $_GET['regularPrice'];
        $discPrice = $_GET['discountedPrice'];
        $productImage = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
        $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];   
        $category = $_GET['category']; 
        $folder = "asset/images/products/".$productImage;
            
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbUsername = "root";
        $dbPassword = "";
        $dbname = "kewalsmart";   

        // Creating Connection
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
        
        if(mysqli_connect_error())
        {
            die('Connection Error('. mysql_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $SELECT = "SELECT email From products Where product_name = ? Limit 1";
            // Get all the submitted data from the form
            $INSERT = "INSERT INTO products (product_name, quantity, regular_price, discounted_price, product_image, category) VALUES ('$productName, $quantity, $regPrice, $discPrice, $productImage, $category')";

            // Prepare Statement
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $productName);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($productName);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

            if($rnum==0)
            {
                $stmt->close();

                $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
                $stmt->bind_param("ssiiss", $productName, $quantity, $regPrice, $discPrice, $productImage, $category);
                $stmt->execute();
                ?>

                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    window.alert("Product Added Successfully");
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                </script>
            
                <?php   
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
                <script>
                    window.alert("Something's Wrong");
                    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "./"; }, 2000);           
                </script>
        
            <?php
            }

            // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder: image
            if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  
            {
                $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = "Failed to upload image";
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
          
        }
    }
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make your form method `post` (and adjust `$_GET` accordingly)

Comment: It was POST earlier but didn't worked so I tried to do it via GET but returning same thing.

Comment: Well, it has to be "post" for uploads to work. Make it "post", run again and post any errors you get. Fyi, `error_reporting(0);` turns off all error reporting

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification on error reporting, that's why I wasn't getting any. This is the one coming 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ..\addproduct.php on line 84

And Line 84 is this 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");

Comment: Disregard the above error please, this one is coming now:


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in ../addproduct.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ..addproduct.php on line 37

Line 37 has this 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $productName);

Comment: Looks like you're mixing object-oriented and procedural mysqli functions/methods. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: Your `$INSERT` contains variables instead of ? placeholders. Fix that and see if the issue goes away

Comment: I have fixed the error and its working properly, thank you everyone for your help